# Appium scoll to an element, without scrollable view

Tags: automated-testing, appium, mobile-automation, android-automation

I have an android app, that has a list page (eg. 20-30 element),

I have to check each list item, how can I scroll to the next list item,
if the app is built like there is no scrollview in it? ( only has a viewgroup - scrollable: false) and views are inside it).

The following code does not work in this case
driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
"new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true))" +
".scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains("partialText"))"));

scrolling manually works ( but its not sure how many new items are scrolled into the view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use actions class from selenium use :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
new Actions(driver).clickAndHold(e2).moveByOffset(0, -500).perform();
```

Note: you have to click and hold element at the bottom of the screen and scroll backwards thats why -500

or move from last element to first element:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.clickAndHold(e2).moveToElement(e1);
action.perform();
```